# If logistic method is calibrated, do I expect the corresponding mixed effect method calibrated?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, logistic, classification, mixed-model

It is known that logistic binary classification is well calibrated.

Q1: If I add random effect into the model where I assume correlation in data structure, do I expect mixed effect logistic regression well calibrated? There is a saddle point here. When I predict subjects not in training sample, I do not have random effect estimation. Thus it is natural to set random effect estimation to 0, though it might be unreasonable.

Q2: If Q1 does not make any sense, then is calibration notion appropriate for mixed effect model at all?